# BrowserModule has already been loaded Error

Tags: angular, typescript

I've updated my application to RC6 and now i keep getting this error:

> zone.js:484 Unhandled Promise rejection: BrowserModule has already
>   been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and
>   NgFor from a lazy loaded module...

I'm using lazy loading and my application is broken up in to a lot of lazy loaded modules. However in RC5 everything worked fine.

The only change I've managed to find in the changelog for RC6 is this:

> compiler: throw descriptive error meesage for invalid NgModule
>   providers

But since i haven't seen any errors in RC5 this probably doesn't apply here.

I'm kind of out of ideas so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I had to import `AppRoutingModule` at the last, that resolved my error. But could not figure out the reason for that.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I've managed to solve my problem. One of the libraries i was using was importing the `BrowserModule`.

I'll just leave the question here in case someone has the same issue.

Comment: Well that's all there is. You should only import BrowserModule once. Other modules you import should be importing CommonModules instead.

Comment: @FilipLauc I am facing the same problem, Did you got the solution?

Comment: Well yes, a library I was using was importing the `BrowserModule` when it should have imported the `CommonModule`

Comment: i'm facing same problem one of my library has imported browser module inside and also i can't change it what need to do ?

Comment: Hello, I have done everything told in this whole thread, removed `BrowserAnimationModule` and `BrowserModule` from child modules and only refs at main module. then I commented out `BrowserModule` and still no luck. Can anyone tell me how to know which libraries are using `BrowserAnimation` module.?

Comment: @FilipLauc hello, How to know which library is using `BrowserModule`?, I have applied every solution told here and other threads on other sites.

Comment: @ImdadAli, unfortunately, I'm not sure how to easily find the library using it. I resorted to removing them one by one until I found the culprit.

Comment: You can use the Augury chrome extension to list all imported modules from libraries at runtime.

Comment: in my case i found this npm package using browsermodule.  removing 
this package solved my problem `npm i @kolkov/ngx-gallery@1.1.0`

Answer (score 98):

I think you are using 'NoopAnimationsModule' or 'BrowserAnimationsModule',
Which already contain 'BrowserModule' and loading your module lazily.
SO the solution is Replace the BrowserModule with 'NoopAnimationsModule or 'BrowserAnimationsModule' in your 'app.module.ts'.

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AdminsModule } from './admins/admins.module';
import { NoopAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
//import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
    ],
    imports: [
    //BrowserModule,
    NoopAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule
],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Comment: this should be the answer :)

Comment: My problem was a bit different.. Actually, I kept both BrowserAnimationModule and BrowserModule in AppModule without any problems. The problem was that I was duplicating the BrowserAnimationModule.

Comment: But what should i do if i need BrowserModule.withServerTransition() (SSR) function and noopAnimationModule?

Comment: If somebody using the shared module to load animation it also can happen. you should remove the BrowserModule from the shared module.

Comment: I found that if you import both BrowserAnimationsModule and BrowserModule (need withServerTransition) both in app.module.ts, the app will run fine. Not sure if the same works with Noop. On ng version 7.2

Answer (score 28):

In my case, I had using BrowserAnimationsModule in each component that is using material design, I removed all reference to "BrowserAnimationsModule" and I put BrowserAnimationsModule in main module.

BrowserAnimationsModule has inculuded BrowserModule, this is the problem.

Answer (score 8):

None of the answers worked for me.

For people still looking for an answer and if you are using a **SharedModule** (and lazy loading) my answer may help you.

**Solution**: Move following exports: `BrowserModule`, `BrowserAnimationsModule`, `HttpModule` and `HttpClientModule` (from SharedModule) to imports in **AppModule**.

Example:

**OLD shared.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [],
   imports: [],
   exports: [
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      // ...
   ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**OLD app.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
   ],
   imports: [
      SharedModule
   ],
   providers: [],
   exports: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**NEW shared.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [],
   imports: [],
   exports: [
      // ...
   ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

**NEW app.module.ts**:

```
@NgModule({
   declarations: [
      AppComponent,
   ],
   imports: [
      BrowserModule,
      BrowserAnimationsModule,
      HttpClientModule,
      SharedModule
   ],
   providers: [],
   exports: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This finally helped me to solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

As the error description is self-explanatory, the module for which you want to implement lazy loading shouldn’t import `BrowserModule` as this is already been imported earlier (mainly in app.component). You should only import `BrowserModule` once. Other modules should be importing `CommonModules` instead.

See the code below for understanding

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common'; //<-- This one 

import { SearchMovieMainComponent } from './search-movies-main.component';

@NgModule({
    imports: [
        CommonModule //<-- and this one 
    ],
    declarations: [
        SearchMovieMainComponent
    ]
})
export class SearchMoviesMainModule {
}
```

**Note**: This is not my own answer. I was facing the same problem. Where I myself have a `CommonModule` in the same name of angular one. So it was real a problem for me, as I was not aware that there is another `CommonModule` that exists in angular itself. I found this [blog](https://hassantariqblog.wordpress.com/2016/10/16/angular2-lazy-loading-in-angular2-error-browsermodule-has-already-been-loaded-if-you-need-access-to-common-directives/) helpful. Posting the answer from there.

Answer (score 2):

I've encountered a simular problem. I have serveral lazyloading modules which all use BrowserAnimationModule(Includes BrowserModule).

My solution first is to move the importation of this module from the child module to the root module as app.module.ts.

```
//app.module.ts
@NgModule({
    declarations: [  ],
    imports: [    BrowserAnimationsModule,]
```

The second step is quite essential, you should also include the CommonModule in each child module .

```
//lazychild.module.ts
@NgModule({
  declarations: [  ],
  imports: [  CommonModule,]
```

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by using this in my `app.component.ts`:

```
import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
  imports: [
..,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
  ],
```

and removed it from anywhere else.

Answer (score 2):

Remove all the import of "BrowserAnimationsModule" as well except from AppModule.

Answer (score 1):

as Described here [Angular Issues Page](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/29906) you can make a `Shared Module` and add all imports in there just once and import that module everywhere you make a new module.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved BrowserModule Already loaded issue**

In My project i import directly  one ownmodule in another childmodule without mentioned in shared module,that why it cause error.