# PrimeNg p-dropdown module does not expand

Tags: angular, primeng

I have a problem with p-dropdown module in Primeng and Angular 4.

I have filled options with values from loop:

```
for(let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
            this.iterations = [... this.iterations, { label: i, value: i}]
        }
```

and I am trying to use it in my template:

```
<p-dropdown [options]="iterations"></p-dropdown>
```

The problem is that dropdown displays first value only (in this case '1'). When I check 'iterations' array or set iterations array statically the problem persists. 
I think I included module correctly in my module. Does DropdownModule depend from any other modules?

```
import {DropdownModule} from 'primeng/primeng'
```

**//edit
I found that it can be something with module html part. Look at image below**

[image]

Regards

Comment: Have you imported BrowserAnimationsModule in you app.module.ts like this `import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';` . Add the module in imports array of @ngmodule decorator as well. Also iterations array should be of type SelectItem in which label can not be integer but string only.

Comment: @TimeTraveler I receive an error:  Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.

Comment: Animtation module is a must import for some of component in primeng to work because these comp use angular's animation, this is clearly stated on primeng setup documentation page. So for the error you are getting depends on where you are importing BrowserModule. check [this-link-to-question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286667/browsermodule-has-already-been-loaded-error) for help. as per thread you may need to remove BrowserModule import from all other places.

Comment: @TimeTraveler I think BrowserAnimationsModule contains BrowserModule thats why I am getting this error. Does it mean I have to choose: lazy loading or working dropdown?

Comment: It should not be like that.I have used lazy loading along with animated components of primeng. You may want to check if you are importing BrowserModule at more than one places. Also BrowserAnimationModule 
and BrowserModule should be imported only once in application root module and no where else. have you checked the link i provided in above comment?

Comment: Yes, I checked. For know I have BrowserAnimationModule imported in my root module, CommonModule in SharedModule and CoreModule (which are imported by root module also). That works and no errors occour but dropdown still does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You must import SelectItem in the component

```
import {SelectItem} from 'primeng/primeng'
```

and the  objects must to implement this interface

```
<p-dropdown [options]="iterations"></p-dropdown>
```

where iterations is the array of SelectItem

```
iterations: SelectItem[];
```

It is the component

```
iterations: SelectItem[];

selectedIteration: string;

ngOnInit() {
    this.iterations = [];
    for(let i = 1; i <= 20; i++) {
        this.iterations.push({ label: i.toString(), value: i.toString() });
    }
}
```

Comment: it does not help :(