# How to use ngx-advanced-searchbox in lazy loaded module?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have successfully implemented [ngx-advanced-searchbox](https://github.com/symrad/ngx-advanced-searchbox) in main module.
But I am unable to use it inside lazy loaded module.

I am getting following error-

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead.
    at new BrowserModule (platform-browser.js:3198)
    at _createClass (core.js:23172)
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only use BrowserModule in one module in your application, usually only in app.module.ts. If you have mulitple modules, you have to import CommonModule in all other modules instead of BrowserModule.

*EDIT*

You can remove `BrowserModule` from your import in app.module, and rely on `ngx-advanced-searchbox` to import it for you.
[Here is a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286667/browsermodule-has-already-been-loaded-error)

Comment: Yes, I understand that error I have imported BrowserModule only in main module. My question is how to use ngx-advanced-searchbox in lazy loaded module.

Comment: @SumitM It seems they import BrowserModule in their module (https://github.com/symrad/ngx-advanced-searchbox/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts). Maybe they should not do that? You could try to remove that import manually in your node_modules folder, just to see if it solves the problem. Then, maybe you can create a pull-request with that change to the library.