# Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded while running angular application

Tags: angular

I've updated my npm packages, now i keep getting this error: "Error: BrowserModule has already been loaded. If you need access to common directives such as NgIf and NgFor from a lazy loaded module, import CommonModule instead."

I tried this ways, but no output:
 1.Import BrowserModule and BrowserAnimationsModule only once in 
 app.module.ts, but still getting the same Issue.
 2. import BrowserModule once in app.module.ts,In Other modules import 
 CommonModules instead.
 3. Remove BrowserModule from app.module.ts because 
  BrowserAnimationsModule by default import BrowserModule
 4. Place BrowserModule on Top of app.module.ts

This is my app.module.ts file code

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    CommonMaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
```

This is my shared.module.ts file code

```
imports: [
    CommonModule,
    CommonMaterialModule,
    ChartsModule,
    FormsModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
    MatExpansionModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CollapseModule,
    MatDialogModule
  ],
```

I tried every way mention in stack overflow to solve issue but getting the same issue. anyone can please help to solve the problem.

Comment: BrowserAnimationsModule already exports BrowserModule with some additional stuffs so you should either use only BrowserModule or BrowserAnimationsModule

Comment: I remove BrowserModule from app.module.ts only import  BrowserAnimationsModule in app.mopdule.ts but still getting same error @Nikola Stekovic

Comment: Can you provide stackblitz code example?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Sure, this is my stackblitz code example URL https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-glcssg

Comment: @sunerapathan unable to see in the console! its working

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BrowserModule has already been loaded Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39286667/browsermodule-has-already-been-loaded-error)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Yes, Same error I got, I unable to find which library is importing BrowserModule again, Can You help to solve issue, I already shared stackblitz link their mention all libraries that i am using.

Comment: @sunerapathan Try to remove `BrowserModule` from your project and then check?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I tried that way, but issue is still their.

Comment: Have you tried another solution from the linked question?

Comment: @PrashantPimpale Sorry, I didn't get it  can you explain in brief.

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of research finally, I got the solution just update angular platform browser dependency which contains BrowerModule.

> npm i @angular/platform-browser

Answer (score 0):

```
imports: [
    BrowserModule<----- comment this
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    HttpModule,<----------------- put this after browser transfer
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    CommonMaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule
  ],
```

> Import BrowserAnimationsModule and HttpModule only once (either in
>   your root module or a core module)

.

Comment: I tried your way @orbit but its not working , Import BrowserAnimationsModule and HttpModule only once in app.module.ts file. below is my code sample.                                imports: [
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    BrowserTransferStateModule,
    HttpModule,
    mainAppRouting,
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    CommonMaterialModule,
    FlexLayoutModule,
  ]